# mimetypes icons missing in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, icons

I need help for a small issue with the Nautilus file manager.

The problem is that it dosen't show mimetypes icons for some file types.
Here's a screenshot :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/t1o5.png

You can see that all of these files (.c++, .h, .py and .class, and even a lot ofothers) have the same icon. It's very hard to distinguish them.
I have elementar luna intall on another hard drivve and with pantheon files manager there's no problem.

So I install the same theme icon theme: no effect.
I installed pantheon-files: it displays the mimetypes of .py file but not the others.
I check if the icons are present in / usr / share / icons /  / mimetypes: they are.
I try to manually specify an icon with assogiate: no effect.

So I need your help for this issue.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This (probably) is because Nautilus is set to display a preview of the file (even if there is none in your case)

Got to Nautilus --> Preferences --> Preview

and set "Show Thumbnails" to "never"...and here they are.

Comment: In my case, I've disabled preview for text files and icons are visible. Thanks